# How to add an archive page to WordPress menus (nav_menu)?

Tags: menus

Isn't there any way to add relative link like **archive page** (**eg** `"host/fruits/"`) of a custom post type I added? (Just as it works `"host/fruits/apple/"`).

Comment: Does archive attribute enabled in your custom post type registration?

Comment: yes, but archive links are not visible in nav_menu.